# What is the value of $1 + {{}^nP_2}/2 +{{}^nP_3}/3 + ~........... ~ {}^nP_n/n $

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

What is the value of $1 + {{}^nP_2}/2 +{{}^nP_3}/3 + ~........... ~ {}^nP_n/n  $

${}^nP_r = \frac {n!} {(n-r)!}$

Attempt: $1 + {{}^nP_2}/2 +{{}^nP_3}/3 + ~........... ~ {}^nP_n/n  $

$= 1 + \frac {n! }{2.(n-2)!} + \frac {n! }{3.(n-3)!} + ........ + \frac {n! }{n.(n-n)!}$

$ = 1 + {}^nC_2 +  {}^nC_3 . 2! +~~ ............~~+ {}^nC_n. (n-1)! $ .........(1)

Now, $(1+x)^n = {}^nC_0 + {}^nC_1 x + {}^nC_2x^2 + ............ + {}^nC_nx^n$

Diferentiating the above doesnt seem to work because in (1), every term has coffecient of the form ${}^nC_r r!$

Help shall be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you calculated the first few values by hand to see (1) what sort of function you're probably looking for and (2) how those fractions will be made to have common denominators?

Comment: What are $P_n2$? This looks like work for generating functions. Imagine a $x^k$ ($k=2,3,4...n$) next to every term, then differentiate, and then add by binomial formula.

Comment: @orion $nP_r = \frac {n!} {(n-r)!}$ . uhmm, you mean first differentiate each term and look for similar terms as in the question? It doesn't really seem to work

Comment: Oops, doesn't really add up to what I wanted. Interesting question.

Comment: This is extremely hard to read. I gather that in (for instance) $nP_3/3$ the $n$ is **not** a multiplicative factor but part of the symbol $nP_3$, which stands for $n(n-1)(n-2)=3!\binom n3$. If you meant to write ${}^nP_3$ (which still is a horrible notation) instead of $nP_3$, type it as `{}^nP_3`.

Comment: So essentially we need to solve $\sum_{r=0}^n {n\choose r}(r-1)!$ which is nicely symmetric and then just correct for the first two terms. This is a much clearer statement. Unfortunately Wolfram Alpha doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Okay, i edited it.

Comment: Here's a combinatorial interpretation: that sum is the number of permutations of $n$ elements with at most one nontrivial cycle. If that cycle has length $k$, we get the $k$th term; at length $1$, that just leaves the identity for a first term of $1$. Not a closed form, though.